# Fastest Linux distribution to boot then run Docker (until daemon up and running)

Tags: linux, virtualization, cloud-computing

We want to find out what is the lowest meaningful boot time in a hypervisor context (VMWare on quite high-end hardware) for a Linux distribution.

All what is required after th VM system initialization is to have Docker daemon up and running. Currently, it takes 22-40 seconds on our system. Is it possible to get under **5 seconds** for example?

A really good [comparison](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/the-five-fastest-booting-linux-distributions/) I can find so far dates back to 2011..

[Distrowatch](https://distrowatch.com/search.php) does not implement search for boot speed.